# Counting columns in a query with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('cl_id_seq'::regclass),
  from_number character varying(30),
  to_number character varying(30),
  message text,
  received_at timestamp with time zone,
  sent_at timestamp with time zone,
  reply_batch boolean DEFAULT false,
  chat_id character varying(20),
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  own_account boolean DEFAULT false,
```

I have the following query which would return chat_ids of conversations only if the **last message** (checked by insert_time column) related to the chat_id has the column own_account to false.

```
select chat_id from message_log 
where own_account = 'f'
and insert_time in
(
select distinct max(insert_time) from message_log group by chat_id
)
```

The above SQL works perfectly but it returns conversations without checking how many times own_account column is true in a chat. I would like to add the ability to return chat_ids of conversations also based on how many times own_account is true.

I have tried many different SQL queries but I can not succeed at making this work. Any help would be appreciated.

I hope I'm clear enough. if confused by anything please comment.

**EDIT**

I have loaded the data on SQL Fiddle here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d7dc/2

If the following query is ran it will return the messages related to a chat conversation

```
select * from message_log where chat_id = '1412' order by insert_time
```

The last message is not from own_account and there are less than 3 own_account messages in the results, so the following query should return it's chat_id but it does not

```
select m.chat_id 
from message_log m
inner join 
  (select chat_id, max(insert_time) as max_insert_time,
   count(case when own_account='t' then 1 else 0 end) as true_count
   from message_log
   group by chat_id) as latest
on m.chat_id = latest.chat_id and
   m.insert_time = latest.max_insert_time
where 
   m.own_account = 'f' and latest.true_count <= 3
```

**EDIT 2**

I have created another sql fiddle here with one record

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad045/1

Comment: the count(case bit should be sum(case

Comment: @Gary I changed it to sum but and I loaded the database with one row with a message having own_account false and it does not return it

Comment: @Gary I just added another fiddle

Comment: @gary accually I think I forgot to change the < to > I think it works perfectly :) I'll test it now

Comment: I just used the new fiddle with the change and got back the record you were expecting.   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ad045/2

Comment: @Gary you are right, my mistake.I have marked it as the correct asnwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a derived table that records the latest insert times for all chats, and then find out if that latest record is `own_account='f'`

```
select m.chat_id 
from message_log m
inner join 
  (select chat_id, max(insert_time) as max_insert_time
   from message_log
   group by chat_id) as latest
on m.chat_id = latest.chat_id and
   m.insert_time = latest.max_insert_time
where 
   m.own_account = 'f'
```

Extending it to find the chats where the latest is own_account='f' but has at least 3 `own_account='t'` entries

```
select m.chat_id 
from message_log m
inner join 
  (select chat_id, max(insert_time) as max_insert_time,
   sum(case when own_account='t' then 1 else 0 end) as true_count
   from message_log
   group by chat_id) as latest
on m.chat_id = latest.chat_id and
   m.insert_time = latest.max_insert_time
where 
   m.own_account = 'f' and latest.true_count >= 3
```

SQLFiddle available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ee8c0/2

Comment: Thanks for your answer by I get an error when I run both queries, I have pasted the error message for the second one here http://pastebin.com/4X57RtDw

Comment: This time there were no error messages, I will check the query's results in the morning and I will accept your answer.

Comment: unfortunately it is not working as I thought, I will show you an example

Comment: I have edited the question. Please take a look at it when you get a chance